# how to make the method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to true(or call) in one tabs of tablayout in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity, android-windowmanager

how to make the method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to true(or call) in one tabs of tablayout in android..

Explanation:

In tablayout onWindowFocusChanged() called automatically in default activity    (true), But  when we click/touch on to the next tab ( which call another activity)
 not able to call the  onWindowFocusChanged() !!!!!!  how to call onWindowFocusChanged() in second tab?

source code:

```
public class TabTestActivity extends TabActivity {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);



            Resources res = getResources();

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  

            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  

            Intent intent;  



            // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabOne.class);



            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TabOne").setIndicator("TabOne",

                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_One))

                          .setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);



            // Do the same for the other tabs

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabTwo.class);

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("TabTwo").setIndicator("TabTwo",

                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_az))

                          .setContent(intent);

            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            //tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

        }


                  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     Toast.makeText(this, ""+hasFocus , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

                    }
  }
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    public class TabOne extends Activity {

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                TextView textview = new TextView(this);

                textview.setText("This is the Coll tab");

                setContentView(textview);

            }

        @Override

        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            Toast.makeText(this, "On window One"+hasFocus , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        }

    }

--------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    public class TabTwo extends Activity {

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



                TextView textview = new TextView(this);

                textview.setText("This is the Coll tab");

                setContentView(textview);

            }



        @Override

        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(this, "On window TabTwo"+hasFocus , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);


        }

  }
```

TabTwo's (2ndTab) onWindowFocusChanged not called while  TabTwo activity runs  please give the solution. 
I tried  to provide  tabHost.setFocusable(true); I doesn't worked!!!

Comment: is TabOne's onWindowFocused called?

Comment: @ sadeshKumar: Yes it calls TabOnes onWindowFocused!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs are basically deprecated. You should use fragments instead. This will clearly handle your issue.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714650/converting-tabactivity-into-fragmentactivity for an example of how to do this.

Comment: thanks :) Like you said Tabactivity with viewpager will be awesome !!